# How do I compare the elements in the array with the elements entered in the textbox sequentially in c#?

Tags: c#

My goal is to actually make a guessing game, so I created two arrays with Mysql data called answers and questions. And what I want to do is take the value from the user and if it is true, for example my first answer 'fashion' matches the guess the user entered in the textbox, I want the label to write correct and continue with the next answer and try to find the next answer

---

My code returns true when I enter my values ​​in the array into the textbox, but I want them to be in order. How do you think I can use the for loop. How do you think I can use the for loop to make an ordered comparison?

```
          for (int i=0;i<cevaplar.Count;i++)
        {
            string tahmin = textBox1.Text;
            if(cevaplar.Contains(tahmin))
            {
                label1.Text = "true";
                continue;
                
                
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "false";
                break;

            }
        }
  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use `"cevaplar.Contains(tahmin)"`. With `contains` you're checking if `tahim` can be found anywhere in your array, without taking any order in account.

The solution to your problem should be quite simple. Just don't use `contains` in this situation but use a simple indexer to compare the elements. Try the following:

Replace:

```
if(cevaplar.Contains(tahmin))
            {
                ...
            }
```

With

```
if(cevaplar[i] == tahim) //here you check only if the i'th element is matching.
            {
                ...
            }
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried this at first but even though I entered the correct answer it said wrong